# horizontal rail to vertical conveyor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, conveyor

I am trying to find a solution at an industrial line problem.

I have a product which is cylinder, ~40 grams, 6cm length x 2cm diameter.
The products (cylinders) are coming from a machine (output) in a horizontal rail. I can adjust the slope of the rail.

I must transfer them to another machine (packing). I must put each product (cylinder) in an vertical elevator belt.

You can understand what I want from the photo below.

[image]

My questioning is what implementation should I use between horizontal rail and elevator.
Any ideas please?
[image]

Comment: Your horizontal (conveyor) belt should be, positioned almost vertically, making a very small angle tilting from the elevating machine, so the tip of the teeth will barely touch the head of the cylinder, and allow the cylinder falls to position by gravity. You need to 
figure out the optimum geometry, and speed of the belts of both machines.

Comment: Could add a gate device on the input side, synchronized with the compartment separators of the vertical belt. When gate opens, lets one cylinder thru. cylinder then rolls out sideways onto another curved transfer slide that twists to almost upright at the ends of the curve, and it then rolls (now nearly standing) into position on the belt. Need a creative sheet metal person for this, it's kindof an art form but very common in factory automation.

Comment: Check out youtube videos of [various parts feeders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlyuHIxSC-A), which might have some parts that you can use as inspiration

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a spring-loaded deploying tool hinged to the end of your horizontal conveyer, as per the figure.

The spring is calibrated to settle under the weight of the cylinder to allow it to slide down and lodge into the vertical bracket, but once empty it will rise up nudging the cylinder tucked in place.

.

[image: deploying arm]

Comment: Interesting approach!